# Non linear programming float decision variable in CPLEX

Tags: nlp, mathematical-optimization

I m working in a *non linear programming* and got some problems that explain me that we can't use float decision variable in CPLEX when using solver **CP**. Help me, if there is some approach or other methods to solve this problem. Thanks

I had just try to use CP in CPLEX studio:

Answer (score 0):

with CPOptimizer you can use float expressions and that way you can use decimal decision variables.

See https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoodecimalcpo.mod

```
using CP;

int nbKids=310;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
int scale=100;

 
dvar int+ scalenbBus40;
dvar int+ scalenbBus30;

dexpr float nbBus40=scalenbBus40/scale;
dexpr float nbBus30=scalenbBus30/scale;
 
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
}

execute
{
  writeln("nbBus40 = ",nbBus40);
  writeln("nbBus30 = ",nbBus30);
}
```